# RMI stub for JMX in tomcat

Tags: java, rmi, jmx

I am creating an RMI stub for JMX similar to the instructions [in this blog post](http://vafer.org/blog/20061010091658/), and it opens a listening port as expected. When I try to connect to the port with JMX I get the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jmxrmi
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:340)
        at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:248)
        at ....
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jmxrmi
        at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:99)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(GenericURLContext.java:185)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(RMIConnector.java:1888)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(RMIConnector.java:1858)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:257)
... 2 more
```

Is there any way for me to debug the RMI server and see why that name can't be found?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that one of the configuration options was pointing to a file that didn't exist. JMX fell over silently :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you left out a ':'. You should have service:jmx:rmi ...

Comment: I get the same error with "jmx:rmi". "jmxrmi" is also what jconsole appears to use by default.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the connector is the last part of the URL (in the blog post it's "connector"). Change that to "jmxrmi".